# How to make UITextfield look like UIAlertView in UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'd like the UITextField in a UIAlertController look like the old UIAlertView (rounded corners, lighter gray).

(sorry, I can not post images at this time...)

How could I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your first post came to me for review. Please make sure you've read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular in this case - you need to show what you've tried to achieve your aim and how it failed - i.e. what the result was and why it wasn't what you wanted.